# Почему не работает добавление нового элемента в базу данных Django через forms

Tags: python, django

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class CreateChatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Пароль")

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ["login", "password"]
        widjets = {
            'login': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "chat-login"})
        }

class CreateMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': "Message..."}))
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ["text"]
```

views.py:

```
def ReadyChat(request, login):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateMessageForm(request.POST)
        form.chat = Chat.objects.get(login=login)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = CreateMessageForm()

    chat = get_object_or_404(Chat, login=login)
    messages = Message.objects.filter(chat__login = login)
    context = {
        "chat": chat,
        "messages": messages,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "main/ReadyChat.html", context)
```

Я не могу добавить элемент Chat в form и сохранить его при помощи form.save(), пишет: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_message.chat_id

Comment: Добавьте код модели Message

Comment: У формы CreateMessageForm нет поля chat. Наверное в этом дело. Можно например добавить это поле и сделать его скрытым. ReadyChat оставить как есть. Не думаю что это лучший вариант, но так должно заработать.